# Is there a Javascript code that can see how full your cache is?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a javascript code that makes it possible to see how much data there is stored in the cache in google chrome?

Comment: No. That is not accessible through Javascript.

Comment: Take a look at the following `experimental` technology: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage/keys.

Comment: I don't think that's the browser's cache, it's an API for applications caching their own data.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in the [Chrome extension API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) to check that, even though you can *empty* the cache using `browsingData` API.

Obviously, less-privileged Web APIs can't access that either.